# Qgis Join attributes by location

Tags: join, attributes, qgis

I have a question regardingg QGIS. I'll try to be as precise as possible in my explication.

I have a shapefile showing different regions in a country and another file (.klm) with the localisation of my sites across the country. My goal is to define for each site a region which is described in the other file. So far so good.

The shapefile had to be modified because the SCR was different. It was a SCR created by another user and I couldn't do anything with it because of the transformation included in it. So I had to save the document as a shapefile in a new SCR. But the problem is not here (or so I think).

The issue comes when I try to join attributes by location. Once the two files are join together i lose most of my sites and the attributes table only gives me a total of 15sites out of more than 300. So it's kind of working but not entirely...
I've tried different things but nothing seems to work and it is always the same 15 sites and I don't understand why only these sites and why only 15. 
Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure your geometries are overlapping - you can have option 'On-The-Fly Re-projection' enabled. Also make sure your regions are polygons not a closed lines.

Comment: @Jendrusk thanks for your comment. I did check the "On-the-fly re" setting..

Comment: I used the plugin Point Sampling Tool and it finally worked :)